# Finding the difference in an arithmetic progression in Lisp

Tags: math, common-lisp

I am **totally** new to Lisp.

How to find the difference between elements in an arithmetic progression series?

e.g.

```
(counted-by-N '(20 10 0))
```

Return `-10`

```
(counted-by-N '(20 10 5))
(counted-by-N '(2))
(counted-by-N '())
```

Returns `Nil`

In Python/C and other languages, it is very straightforward... Kinda stuck here in Lisp.

My pseudo algorithm would be something like this:

```
function counted-by-N(L):
    if len(L) <= 1:
        return Nil
    else:
        diff = L[second] - L[first]
        for (i = second; i < len(L) - 1; i++):
            if L[i+1] - L[i] != diff
                return Nil
        return diff
```

---

Current work:

```
(defun count-by-N (L)
    (if (<= (length L) 1) Nil
    (
        (defvar diff (- (second L) (first L)))
        ; How to do the loop part?
    ))
)
```

Comment: @Marcin Here is my pseudo code. I don't know how to convert this when there is no variable stored, or using for loop in Lisp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my final answer of this question which uses recursion:

```
(defun diff (N)
    (- (second N) (first N))
)

(defun count-by-N (L)
    (cond
        ((null L)          nil)
        ((= (length L) 1)  nil)
        ((= (length L) 2) (diff L))
        ((= (diff L) (diff (rest L))) (count-by-N (rest L)))
        (T nil)
    )
)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
(flet ((by-n (list &aux
                   (e1 (first list))
                   (e2 (second list))
                   (difference (and e1 e2 (- e2 e1))))
         (and difference
              (loop for (one two) on list
                    while (and one two)
                    when (/= (- two one) difference)
                    do (return-from by-n nil)))
         difference))

  (by-n '(20 10 0)))
```

or

```
(flet ((by-n (list &aux
                   (e1 (first list))
                   (e2 (second list))
                   (difference (and e1 e2 (- e2 e1))))
         (when difference
           (loop for (one two) on list
                 while (and one two)
                 when (/= (- two one) difference)
                 do (return-from by-n nil))
           difference)))

  (by-n '(20 10 0)))
```

Comment: You should exchange the operands of `-` to get the value requested by the question (-10, not 10, in the last example).

Answer (score 2):

As far as you said on the second answer the best choice you have to do this example is implement it recursively.

## Example Using List Processing (good manners)

That way, you have some ways to do this example on the recursively and simple way:

```
(defun count-by-N-1 (lst)
  (if (equal NIL lst)
    NIL
    (- (car (cdr lst)) (car lst))
  )
  (count-by-N-1 (cdr lst))
)
```

On this first approach of the function `count-by-N-1` I am using the simple `car` and `cdr` instructions to simplify the basics of Common Lisp List transformations.

## Example Using List Processing Shortcuts (best implementation)

However you can resume by using some shortcuts of the `car` and `cdr` instructions like when you want to do a a `car` of a `cdr`, like I did on this example:

```
(defun count-by-N-2 (lst)
  (if (equal NIL lst)
    NIL
    (- (cadr lst) (car lst))
  )
  (count-by-N-2 (cdr lst))
)
```

If you have some problems to understand this kind of questions using basic instructions of Common Lisp List transformation as well as `car` and `cdr`, you still can choose the `first`, `second` and `rest` approach. However I recommend you to see some of this basic instructions first:

http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/they-called-it-lisp-for-a-reason-list-processing.html

## Example Using Accessors (best for understand)

```
(defun count-by-N-3 (lst)
  (if (equal NIL lst)
    NIL
    (- (first (rest lst)) (first lst))
  )
  (count-by-N-3 (rest lst))
)
```

This last one, the one that I will explain more clearly since it is the most understandable, you will do a recursion list manipulation (as in the others examples), and like the others, until the list is not `NIL` it will get the first element of the rest of the list and subtract the first element of the same list. The program will do this for every element till the list is "clean". And at last returns the list with the subtracted values.

That way if you read and study the similarities between using `first`, `second` and `rest` approach against using `car` and `cdr`, you easily will understand the both two first examples that I did put here.

Comment: Please note that all the functions in your answer produces always type error (SBCL) or enter in an infinite loop (CCL).